# setMaxDate value cannot be set to 18 year back

Tags: java, android, plugins

I am trying to set the maxdate value to 18year before, but I couldn't do it.

```
setMaxDate(new Date().getTime()-18*365*24*60*60*1000);
```

I am using the above method and I would like to use only this menthod. Kindly help

Comment: On what object are you trying to `setMaxDate`?

Comment: Also remember some years have leap days..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`18*365*24*60*60*1000` is a number too large to fit in a 32-bit signed integer. Change it to a  64-bit signed long integer: `18*365*24*60*60*1000L` (notice the `L`).

But there are better methods to go 18 years back, e.g.

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(); // current date
c.add(Calendar.YEAR, -18);
Date t = c.getTime(); // to convert to Date
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are passing `Date` parameter to `setMaxDate` function then it should be

```
setMaxDate( new Date( new Date().getTime()- 1L * 18 * 365 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 ) );
```